# Getting "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 20 out of bounds for length 4" while using for-each loop with ArrayList of integers

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to learn, so don't blast me please.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Dummy {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    values.add(20);
    values.add(10);
    values.add(50);
    values.add(20);

    System.out.println(add(values));

  }

  static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  static int add(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
  }

  static int add(ArrayList<Integer> values) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i : values) {
      sum += values.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
  }

}
```

So, this is a simple code that I was using for learning some stuff. I tried to create a sum method with an ArrayList of integers as a parameter. I tried to use a for-each loop to sum each value, but I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 20 out of bounds for length 4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at Dummy.add(Dummy.java:29)
    at Dummy.main(Dummy.java:13)
[Finished in 1.245s]
```

I don't understand why I get this error, if I use a simple for loop it works. Sorry if it's a stupid question but like I said, I'm trying to learn so please be kind with me, thanks.

Comment: Closely related: "[What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5554734/90527)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/85190/90527)"

Answer (score 1):

The `for-each` loop iterates the values, not the indexes.

```
for (int i : values) {
  sum += values.get(i);
}
```

should be

```
for (int i : values) {
  sum += i;
}
```

If using Java 8+, you could map to an `IntStream` and sum like

```
static int add(List<Integer> values) {
    return values.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
}
```